# Prove a random variable is sub-Gaussian

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Given $X$ a sub-Gaussian random variable  with parameter $\sigma$. i.e.,
$$
\mathbb{E} \exp(t(X-\mu)) \le \exp (t^2\sigma^2/2),
$$
where $\mu = \mathbb{E} X$. Can we prove that if $\sigma$ is large enough, $X+ \frac{1}{1+\exp(X)}$ is also sub-gaussian with parameter $\sigma$?

Comment: $\exp(X)>0$ so $X \le X+ \frac{1}{1+\exp(X)}\le X+1$

Comment: But we need the same parameter here.